HVAC working perfectly with regular thermostat, then AC not working with smart thermostat
My home had an old, simple Honeywell thermostat that was working completely fine. See the photograph attached for wiring information. I am in Texas, so I have both an external AC compressor and a furnace, with a forced air system.
I bought an Amazon Smart Thermostat and wired it exactly as shown in the other diagram attached: blue wire in the C terminal, yellow on Y, green on G, white on W and red on R. There is a switch to the left of Rc that, when pulled up, is supposed to short R and Rc, effectively making them the same. This switch is up.
My issue: heating and fan work perfectly, but the compressor never turns on when the AC is activated. If I set the thermostat to cooling, the fan will turn on but the compressor doesn't run at all.
For testing purposes, I also:

Bought another Amazon Smart Thermostat (in case the hardware was the problem). Same issue occurred.
Tried plugging in the red wire straight to Rc. Same issue (didn't test the heating, though, but I assume it wouldn't work).
Reinstalled the simple Honeywell thermostat I had before. The system works perfectly.
Checked my other home, where the AC works fine with the Amazon thermostat; there, the white wire is connected to O/B instead of W. NOTE: the O/B and W wires appear to be the same in the Honeywell thermostat, but different in the Amazon Smart Thermostat. Wondering if I should just give this a try.




How long did you let the Amazon thermostat sit in cooling mode? After powering on it may delay many minutes before heeding your setting for cooling. (I've only worked with an Amazon t-stat once, and it was painful waiting for that thing to call for cooling right after I installed it.) Have you checked the wiring at the furnace end to be sure the colors are connected in the conventional way?

Well, I wouldn't think Texas is cold enough yet that the compressor temperature lockout mechanism would activate.  Is the R jumper slider set correctly—up or down?

@GregHill I’m aware about the delayed start. I left it alone for a couple of hours

@Huesmann It was set up (I tried two Amazon thermostats). The temperature was between 70 and 80 F all day
